# Navbar mobile view 2 lines

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

If the navbar is in mobile view and you click on the hamburger, the navbar goes to 2 lines. How do I solve this?

There's something wrong with the order-1. I would like to have the hamburger on the left in mobile view.

I've been playing with it for a while now but can't seem to fix the problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfCch.jpg)

Here is the code:

```css
.bg-light {
    background-color: #0c66eb !important;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .navbar-header {
        display: flex;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .navbar-brand {
        order: 1;
    display: flex !important;
    }
}


/* mobile navbar sidebar under lg breakpoint */
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .navbar-collapse.collapsing .navbar-nav {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: -45%;
        transition: all 0.2s ease;
    }

    .navbar-collapse.show .navbar-nav {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: auto;
        width: 45%;
        background-color: #fff !important;
        transition: left 0.35s ease;
        box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">logo</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav m-0 p-3 p-lg-0">
                <li class="d-inline d-lg-none">
                    <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav" class="close float-right">&times;</button>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown ml-auto">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Dropdown link </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
</nav>
<link media="screen" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: The nav goes on to two lines because in the bootstrap css, the div with class .container has the flex-wrap property is set to wrap. You need to add a class and override this to flex-wrap:nowrap !important

Answer (score 0):

Delete this code:

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-brand {
     order: 1;
    display: flex !important;
  }
}
```

and swap between each other "a.navbar-brand" and "button.navbar-toggler".

```css
.bg-light {
    background-color: #0c66eb !important;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .navbar-header {
        display: flex;
    }
}


/* mobile navbar sidebar under lg breakpoint */
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .navbar-collapse.collapsing .navbar-nav {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: -45%;
        transition: all 0.2s ease;
    }

    .navbar-collapse.show .navbar-nav {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: auto;
        width: 45%;
        background-color: #fff !important;
        transition: left 0.35s ease;
        box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
         

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">logo</a>
        
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav m-0 p-3 p-lg-0">
                <li class="d-inline d-lg-none">
                    <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav" class="close float-right">&times;</button>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown ml-auto">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Dropdown link </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
</nav>
<link media="screen" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```